# How to start to create an application GUI using C#?

Tags: c#, user-interface

HI!

I am new to C# and plan to use it for my application GUI. I am trying to make my GUI similar to SPSS:http://www.spss.com/images/08/statistics_screens/ez_rfm-big.jpg

Is this easy in C#? Is there a template that has done most of it? (Like MDI/SDI framework in MFC)

Could someone suggest some big examples(some working/half-working source code for me to study?)

Thanks,
Yin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah its very easy to create GUI using C# on .NET platform. For your purpose. You are going to need following classes/Controls:

1. Form
2. MenuStrip
3. Toolstrip
4. StatusStrip
5. DataView/DataGridView
6. TextBox
7. Label
8. TabControl
9. TabPage
10. PictureBox
11. Button

and others  (which you need to figure out).

just go through these classes in MSDN (you'll find many examples there). If you want to quickstart. Otherwise I get a good book to have solid foundations.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. But don't forget to mark the answer when you think you got an answer.

Comment: Should be noted that this is based on WinForms :)

Answer (score 2):

there is lot of Win forms videos on controls you might need [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb798022.aspx) just scroll down to Windows Forms Controls Series

Comment: Watch the ones you are most intrested in.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your Visual Studio simply create new WinForm project, where you can just drag-and-drop controls from the toolbar and edit their look&feel in design mode.